# How does one interpret the fitmeasures() function in the lavaan class in R?

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I want to understand the output of the fitmeasures() from the lavaan class in RStudio. I'm learning R on my own and would love some help on deciphering what these values mean.

Values included are 'npar', 'fmin', 'pnfi','cfi', 'ifi', 'tli', 'crmr', etc.

I can't seem to find interpretations of the output. Instead, there are a lot of resources on how to construct the code. Below is context for which I find the code.

```
#one example

a <- cfa(cfa1, data = x[x$a == 0, ], meanstructure = T)
summary(a)
fitmeasures(a)

#another example

config <- cfa(cfa1, data = x, meanstructure = T, group = "b")
summary(config)
fitmeasures(config)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still looking but just found this really helpful article which explains what you probably need to know.  it doesn't explain all of these values but it sets out how to do the cfa and efa analysis that use these `fitMeasures` in the output.

The set consists of:

1. A paper
2. A supplementary paper
3. R code file
4. Input file of test data.

Article:

"One Size Doesn’t Fit All: Using Factor Analysis to Gather Validity Evidence When Using Surveys in Your Research"
Eva Knekta, Christopher Runyon, and Sarah Eddy
CBE—Life Sciences Education 2019 18:1

Here is the link to the page where you can download the paper and don't forget the zip file of supplementary materials.

https://www.lifescied.org/doi/full/10.1187/cbe.18-04-0064

Cheers